# Fix Odd and Even Selector

Tags: jquery, html, css

i have this css rule,

```
.messagesContent:nth-child(even){
    float: right;
    background: white;
}
.messagesContent:nth-child(odd){
    float: left;
    background: #ccc;
}
```

i use jquery to add an element before all elements ,
with this

```
var c = $("#content_2").find(".mCSB_container li:first");
result = eval(result);
c.before(result.html);
```

if it add to dom , the background color of elements change (even and odd changes)
how can i prevent this change?

Comment: Well, before you add items to the dom, you could go through and add .even and .odd classes to them.  Then change your :nth-child() to just .even and .odd.

Comment: Why exactly is the background color change _not_ the right thing? It seems like you should be happy it does this for you :)

Comment: +1 @Richard, I was about to recommend classes as well. psuedo-class use with dynamic elements is tricky business, using a class instead will ensure consistency. as a side note, you really should stay away from CSS selectors in jQuery for performance reasons ... `$('#content_2').find('.mCSV_container').find('li').first()` will run faster.

Comment: @Richard this is good solution, but i don't want to care about element classes!

Comment: @NimaGhaedsharafi Keep it simple and it'll be more robust, more reliable, and more compatible.  Classes are the best solution.

Comment: @Richard please post you answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, add the even/odd class to the items:

```
$(".messagesContent").each(function(i,obj) {
   $(obj).addClass( (i % 2 === 0 ? "even" : "odd"));
});
```

Then add your nodes after that point.

Also, change your CSS rules to ".even" and ".odd" instead of :nth-child()

Comment: Haven't tested it... not sure if it would run, but it looks right.

Answer (score 0):

If you only add 1 element to the list, then the odd/even style will switch.  If you don't want them to switch, you need to add the new element to the bottom of the list or add an even number of new elements.

Here's a simple example of adding to the top or bottom of the list: http://jsfiddle.net/VHm7z/1 where you can add items to either the top or the bottom of a list.

Say you have list where list is a jQuery object for a UL element and li is a jQuery object for a LI element:

```
list.append(li);  // adds to bottom of list
```

Or

```
list.prepend(li);  // adds to top of list
```

Comment: Adding a new item to the bottom won't work, but adding an even number would solve it.

Comment: @Richard Adding to the bottom of the list won't change the bg color of other list items, though the order of the items might not be desirable.

Comment: result.html might have more than one list item, too, I guess.  That would also through it off.

Comment: `[div1] [div2] [div3]` If you add an item before and after `[div2]`, you will change it from an even item to an odd item.  1 and 3 will stay the same, but now you will have [even, even, even] instead of [odd, even, odd].  If you prepend the item before [div1], you'll change the ordinality of 1, 2, and 3 to [even, odd, even] instead of [odd, even,odd].  Regardless of what you add at the end of the list.

Comment: I don't think I said otherwise.  The example on jsfiddle I posted merely shows what happens to existing items when you add to the top vs. adding to the bottom.  I think the original question show that the new content will always be added before so potential answers are what you posted about using classnames instead of psuedo-selectors or adding the items to the bottom of the list instead of to the top. :)

Answer (score 0):

if they are all li elements, it's natural that the background images change since your code works with odd and even elements, and you are adding an extra element on top.  maybe create a rule for first child that it's always the same color, that could prevent it.